# django urls invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to convert urls in django project from url to path.

This is what I have now and I'm getting an invalid syntax on the last comma

Any idea why? Is there something I'm missing

```
urlpatterns = [

    path(
        'favicon.ico',
        RedirectView.as_view(
            url=staticfiles_storage.url('assets/icons/favicon.ico'),
            permanent=False
        ),
        name="favicon"
    ),

    path('bets/', include('bets.paths'),

    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'base_login.html'}, name='login'),

    path('logout/', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.password_reset, 
          {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_form.html'}, name='password_reset'),

    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_done, 
          {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',
          auth_views.password_reset_confirm, 
          {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'}, 
          name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_complete, 
          {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_complete.html'}, 
          name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code to make it more readable

Comment: @KevinHe i've indented it properly now

Comment: `path('bets/', include('bets.paths'),` doesn't have balanced parentheses.  If the editor you're using doesn't have some way of indicating matching parentheses, throw it away and get one that's actually suitable for programming.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm using pycharm community edition and I'm beginning to hate it! I never heard of balanced parentheses before. That's the line that's causing the issue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted the code for you (using [autopep8](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/formatting/) + [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)) and fixed the missing `)`:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path(
        'favicon.ico',
        RedirectView.as_view(
            url=staticfiles_storage.url('assets/icons/favicon.ico'),
            permanent=False
        ),
        name="favicon"
    ),

    path('bets/', include('bets.paths')),

    path('login/', auth_views.login,
         {'template_name': 'base_login.html'}, name='login'),

    path('logout/', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.password_reset,
         {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_form.html'}, name='password_reset'),

    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_done,
         {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',
         auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
         {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'},
         name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_complete,
         {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_complete.html'},
         name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

credits to: [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper)